# Name of style often used in sport-related logos

Tags: style-identification

Here are some examples of what I am looking a name for:

[source](http://logos.co/design/royalty-free-clip-art-vector-black-and-white-sporty-stick-people-logos-by-seamartini-graphics-8950)

[image]

[source](http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-people-logos_800577.htm)

[image]

[source](http://logos.co/design/royalty-free-clip-art-vector-logos-of-joyous-colorful-people-dancing-and-leaping-by-seamartini-graphics-8316)

[image]

[source](http://freedesignfile.com/24314-sports-for-logo-people-design-vector-03/)

[image]

Is there a distinct name for this style?

Comment: No particular style. But I think a lot of people would call those 'pictograms' ala the Olympic Pictograms: http://www.rio2016.com/en/more-information/games-design/pictograms

Comment: a pictogram or pictograph is a symbol, it doesn't implicate any particular style.

Comment: I'd like to suggest "ribbon people"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pictogram or icon would be the most likely term used for these types of figures. See [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pictogram) for more information. Of graphic design interest would be the image of the [swimming pictogram signage from the 1972 Munich Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Piktogramm_Schwimmer_an_der_Muenchner_Olympia_Schwimmhalle.JPG) in that article.